# Best Window Controller Method For Initializing User Defaults

Tags: objective-c, nsuserdefaults, nswindowcontroller

There is a slight delay when initializing checkboxes in my window when reading user defaults and setting them in `windowDidLoad`. Is there a better place to do this?

This is the code in my preference window controller class.

```
- (void)windowDidLoad
{
    [super windowDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"Preferences nib loaded.");

    [showLikesCheckbox setState:[self showLikes]];
    [showFollowsCheckbox setState:[self showFollows]];
    [showCommentsCheckbox setState:[self showComments]];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method `-awakeFromNib` is recommended for doing this.

Comment: I also use awakeFromNib to do this.